# NoClassDefFoundError при компиляции LWJGL 3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

Работаю в `Intellij Idea`. Добавил самый последный билд `LWJGL Nightly` через <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> добавил `lwjgl.jar`, `javadoc.jar`, `src.zip`, и папку `native`. Многие пишут что не подключены *нативные* файлы, но я их добавил и исключение все равно выскакивает. В чем заключается корень проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено. Я добавлял библиотеку из места, отличного от корня проекта и его подпапок. В общем решается эта проблема копированием библиотеки в корень (наверное можно и в любую подпапку корня) и назначение путей до нативных библиотек и библиотеки классов проекта (Как минимум. Еще может быть документация и исходники)